# Rendering a WriteableBitmap within Application_Deactivated event causes app to fail to re-activate after suspension

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-tile, tombstoning

I am building a Windows Phone 8 version of an app that I already have for Windows Phone 7.1, which works perfectly.
Inside the `Application_Deactivated` event (in `App.xaml.cs`) I attempt to update the secondary tile of my app, if pinned to the start screen. Because it is a custom tile, I build it in code using a grid and by adding elements to it. So in the final step, I have something like (`layoutRoot` is of type `Grid`) :

```
layoutRoot.Measure(new Size(336, 336));
layoutRoot.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 336, 336));
layoutRoot.UpdateLayout();

WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(336, 336);
bitmap.Render(layoutRoot, null);
bitmap.Invalidate();

using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (Stream fileStream = storage.CreateFile("/Shared/ShellContent/BackBackgroundImage.png"))
            {
                bitmap.SaveJpeg(fileStream, 336, 336, 0, 100);
            }
        }
```

So then I can update the Tile very easily. The problem is that when the app is running and I tap the "Windows" button, the app is successfully suspended and the Tile updated, but when I hit "back" to make it active again, a default "loading" text is shown on screen and nothing will happen. However, I have noticed that by commenting out the line `bitmap.Render(layoutRoot, null);`, the app is re-activated successfully and it works fine, despite the fact that the Tile does not get updated upon suspension, as expected.

In the WP7.1 version of the app, this never happens, although the method for updating the Tile is the same. I really cannot figure out what is going on. Any comment/suggestion/advice will be appreciated.

Edit. `Aplication_Deactivated` code:

```
        private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateLiveTile(); //Generate Tile content (as shown above) and update the Tile if it is pinned
        ExportData(); //Writes data in a file
        StartPeriodicAgent(); //Starts the periodic background agent that updates the live tile
    }
```

Comment: Show your Application_Deactivated code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should consider moving this code to OnNavigatedFrom event handler of the page(s). There can be side effects, because `bitmap.Render` require UI thread to render your xaml code.

Comment: But the same piece of code seems to be perfectly working in the WP7.1 app, regardless of whether it is executed on a WP8 or WP7.1 device. Why should it be different on a WP8 app?

Comment: WP8 is very different from WP7 at the very deep level. So, there can be side effects. WP7 is based on Windows CE, but WP8 on Windows NT. You can try to debug this situation with catching exceptions to the log especially where the render function is called.

Comment: I tried putting the Tile update code in `OnNavigatedTo` or `OnNavigatedFrom` of the page, but it seems that more problems are created rather than resolved. By putting this code in `Application_Deactivated`, the `bitmap.Render` command works fine and the Tile is updated. The problem is that when the user navigates away from the app, for example by sharing app content on Facebook, when he/she returns to the app, it freezes. And this does not happen only if `bitmap.Render` is commented out. But this is really weird, as the command itself is successfully executed with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:**

```
RootFrame.Navigating += RootFrame_Navigating;
void RootFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Uri.OriginalString=="app://external/")
    {
        // update the custom tiles here and the resume error is gone..
    }
}
```

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22256.windows-phone-8-writeablebitmap-and-app-resume.aspx